# Funnction saves the result from previus calls and uses it instead of an argument

Tags: python

You dont have to understand the whole code -  the problem is in one line.

*Sorry for non-english words*

This is thе whole code: imports, arguments, function, function call, **which works OK**:

```
import pymorphy2
import re

def lemmatization(string, expression, morh):
    string = string.lstrip()
    print("1 ", string, "\n")
    lemmatised_string = []
    for line in string.splitlines():
        line = expression.sub("", line).split()
        for word in line:
            m = morph.parse(word)
            if m:
                m = m[0]
                if m.tag.POS not in ("NUMR", "PREP", "CONJ", "PRCL", "INTJ"):
                    lemmatised_string.append(m.normal_form)   
    return lemmatised_string

data = """ Я вышел не пойми откуда и зашел к собакам """
punctuation = re.compile("[\\d\\{}]".format("\\".join(string.punctuation)))
morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()

lemmatized_string = lemmatization(data, punctuation, morph)
```

The function works OKay and returns a list: `['я','выйти','понять','откуда','зайти','собака']`

But i wanted it to return this list like a sentence:

`"я выйти понять куда откуда зайти собака"` ,

So, added one line just before `return`:

```
def lemmatization(string, expression, morh):
    string = string.lstrip()
    print("1 ", string, "\n")
    lemmatised_string = []
    for line in string.splitlines():
        line = expression.sub("", line).split()
        for word in line:
            m = morph.parse(word)
            if m:
                m = m[0]
                if m.tag.POS not in ("NUMR", "PREP", "CONJ", "PRCL", "INTJ"):
                    lemmatised_string.append(m.normal_form)  

    lemmatised_string = " ".join(lemmatized_string) #####<- THIS LINE
    return lemmatised_string
```

First time, i called the function, it worked OKay and united the list in one string just like i wanted.
 **BUT**, when i called the function again, it seemed to be called on `lemmatised_string`, **NOT** the `data`! Here'is the result of second call:

```
я   в ы й т и   п о н я т ь   о т к у д а   з а й т и   с о б а к а
```

The argument `data` is still the same and didn't change! But the function returns diffrent results every call!! The function itself somehow saves the result of a previous call! What happens?

Comment: Your code works fine for me ( python 2.7 ) . Can you include the part where you call `lemmatization` the second time ?

Comment: @t.m.adam I just re-ran the cell where i called it for the first time. Just re-run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be more careful when naming your variables , it can be confusing or lead to errors that are very difficult to debug .
In this case you seem to have joined `lemmatized_string` which i assume is defined somewhere in your script .

Can you replace those lines :

```
lemmatised_string = " ".join(lemmatized_string) 
return lemmatised_string
```

with this :

```
return " ".join(lemmatised_string)
```

Full code :

```
import string
import re
import pymorphy2

def lemmatization(my_string, expression, morh):
    my_string = my_string.lstrip()
    print("1 ", my_string, "\n")
    lemmatised_string = []
    for line in my_string.splitlines():
        line = expression.sub("", line).split()
        for word in line:
            m = morph.parse(word)
            if m:
                m = m[0]
                if m.tag.POS not in ("NUMR", "PREP", "CONJ", "PRCL", "INTJ"):
                    lemmatised_string.append(m.normal_form)  

    return " ".join(lemmatised_string)

#data = """ Я вышел не пойми откуда и зашел к собакам """
data = " Some random ASCII string. "

punctuation = re.compile("[\\d\\{}]".format("\\".join(string.punctuation)))
morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()

lemmatized_string1 = lemmatization(data, punctuation, morph)
lemmatized_string2 = lemmatization(data, punctuation, morph)

print(lemmatized_string1)
print(lemmatized_string2)
```

This should print :

```
1  Some random ASCII string.

1  Some random ASCII string.

some random ascii string
some random ascii string
```

Comment: Ops, that didnt help :/

Comment: I don't get it . Mabe it is about encoding cyrillic , i couldn't print your string in windows terminal . If not , can you copy - paste the code in my post in a new file , and try again ?

Comment: Okay, i see your example works fine. I'll take the rest for my own study. Thaks